# How can I make Autocomplete not show the Value field and just the Text field?

Tags: acumatica

I have a selector that displays employees and a key field of the employee ID (BAccountID). If the user types in an employee name, the autocomplete will show them ID - EmployeeName. How do I hide the ID (Value) field and just display the EmployeeName (Text)?

Auto complete:

[image]

Selector:

[image]

Selector Code:

```
    [PXDBInt]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Requested By")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<BAccount2.bAccountID, Where<BAccount2.type, Equal<EP>>>),
    new Type[]
    {
         typeof(BAccount2.acctName)
    },
    DescriptionField = typeof(BAccountR.acctName),
       Filterable = true
    //FilterEntity = typeof(BAccountR.acctName) 
    )]
```

Object Setup:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I failed to influence the editor auto-complete feature using DAC attribute or customization properties. It simply can't be done without JavaScript it seems.

You could create a feature request for it:
https://feedback.acumatica.com/

Comment: Thanks for trying HB! I always appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The property you are looking for is 'SubstituteKey'

```
    [PXDBInt]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Requested By")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<BAccount2.bAccountID, Where<BAccount2.type, Equal<EP>>>), SubstituteKey = typeof(BAccount2.acctName), DescriptionField = typeof(BAccount2.acctName),
   Filterable = true)]
```

Also given the records you are selecting a [PXDimensionSelectorAttribute] would be more appropriate for your use.

Comment: While the substitute key will indeed fix the problem, it should also be noted that when selecting from BAccount, a PXDimensionSelector should be used instead of PXSelector.

Comment: I will try the PXDimentionSelector, but I did use substitute key and that cause an error since it was trying to save the AcctName where I wanted a BAccountID.

Comment: From your comment it sounds as if your original selector was selecting BAccount2.AcctName instead of searching BAccount2.BAccountID and setting the SubstituteKey = typeof(Baccount2.AcctName)], also be careful in your selectors to be consistent on the data type you are selecting.

Comment: Interesting approach. I thought this would only replace the key instead of getting rid of them, ex: "key1 - value" is substituted with "key2 - value". That's quite an improvement though going from "1343 - John" to "John - John". Or maybe I'm completely wrong and you can remove the key with this technique?